# jQuery make div 200% bigger on click

Tags: jquery

I have a welcome div that on the click of a link inside I wish to expand by double. The problem I have is that the width at start is in percentage of the holding div so 100%, I want to make the div on link click animate expand to 200%, then if clicked link again animate back, here is what I have:

```
var enlarged = false;

$('.welcome a.expand').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.welcome').stop(true, false).animate({
        width: enlarged ? 100 : 200,  // Original width is 100%
        height: enlarged ? 355 : 455, // Original height is 355px
    }, 200);

    enlarged = !enlarged;
});
```

I understand that jQuery is using the figures I have given as px based so the 100 and 200 in the width setting I need to be % based.

I also have additional paragraphs of text that i want to show once the div has expanded so a delay in this, then of course I would need to remove the paragraphs first when closing and have a delay on returning the div to normal width and height.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you post some `html` too?

Comment: I have a fiddle here, as mentioned some paragraphs are hidden then i need to show once expanded, the height expanded can be anything at the moment as we can set this based on content after.

https://jsfiddle.net/t7yyr7tw/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution for jQuery which is not depending on hard-coded height and width values:

```
var enlarged = false;

$('.enlarge').on('click', function() {
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
  var $p = $(this).find('p')

  if (!enlarged) {
    width = width * 2;
    height = height * 2;
    enlarged = true;
    var callback = function($this) {
      $this.show();
    };
  } else {
    width = width / 2;
    height = height / 2;
    enlarged = false;
    var callback = function($this) {
      $this.hide();
    };
  }

  $(this).stop().animate({
    width: width,
    height: height
  }, callback($p));

});
```

I'm adding a callback-function to `animate()` to show or hide the paragraphs inside the div.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0kd948nt/1/)**

Comment: This is pretty close, I just need to remove the paragraphs on close and delay the box closing until these have been removed.....thanks :)

Comment: @Geoff so the "opening" is ok, but for closing it should be the other way round like I did it?

Answer (score 6):

If I were you, I would use CSS.

```js
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass("active")})
})
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: #a00;
  margin:100px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

div.active {
  transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>asd</div>
```

---

So there is a comment on OP doesn't want to enlarge the content, here is another snippet.

```js
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass("active")})
})
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: #a00;
  margin:100px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

div.active {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>asd</div>
```

---

If you want to support older browsers (namely IE 10-)

```js
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var targetw = 100;
        var targeth = 100;
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          targetw *= 2;
          targeth *= 2;
        }
        $(this).animate({width:targetw, height:targeth});
    })
})
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: #a00;
  margin:100px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>asd</div>
```

Comment: OP doesn't needs `scale()`, needs grow `width` and `height`, but not its contents. However, this is the right direction.

Comment: Please note the browser-support for [transition](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude fixed

Comment: I upvote you, right now is a great and complete answer

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks

Comment: very useful answer, Can this target div by name?

Comment: @Phil3992 If you are new to jQuery, you should look up jQuery selector. Just switch out `$("div")` with another selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try The Same using CSS

I am adding the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nexus5786/5L0yvqda/

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".but").click(function(){
    $(".test").toggleClass("large");
```

});

Thanks